# Javascript Date function to call next function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a script in javascript with a date (eg. July) and then do a particular function, in my example `hello()`. Now I want it to keep saying hello even though it is not July.

What I have is:

```
function update1() {
  var d = new date();
  var n = d.getMonth();

  if (n === 6 && n >= 0) { //now when it passes july this statement will be ignored.
    //I know that I can do this for every month, but I want it in a simpler way
    hello();
  }
}

function hello() {
  document.write("hello");
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use || in the if statement then that will bypass checking if it is july.

Comment: So you want to run a function based on what month it is? So it should output `January Hello`, `February Hello`, "March Hello`, etc.?

Comment: If you want it to say hello regardless of wether or not it's july, then what's the point of the checking if it's july?

Comment: Firstly, `var d = new Date();`, `date()` from bug letter. And when and where do you call `update1()`?

Comment: I think I can say in the if statement if(n ===1 || n=== 2, etc){ call function hello(); }

Comment: @ArtOlshansky July is 6 (the seventh month)

Comment: @KooiInc my bad

Comment: yes to itsanewabstract

Comment: your conditional's  n>=0 is redundant.  n>=0&&n===6 is the same as n===6.  It sounds like what you're asking for is just if(n>=6)  or  if(n<=6)?

Comment: If you're saying you want it to print hello from any date after the next coming July.  eg:  after July 2020, you need to check the date 2020-07 and not just the month.  There's no way for the program to know when it runs after July 2020 that it was run before that date without storing state (in this case the year) eg: if you run it in 2021 the program has no way of knowing it should check that it is after 2020 and not July 2021 unless you specify it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean. Something like the snippet (where `notHello` is just for demo purposes)?

```js
const months = "januari,february,march,april,may,june,july,august,september,october,november,december".split(",")
const notHello = month => console.log(`It's ${months[month]}, so hello will not be called`);
const hello = month => console.log(`Hello, it's ${months[month]}, so not july yet`);
const update1 = () => {
  const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth(); 
  if (currentMonth <= 6) {
    return hello(currentMonth);
  } 
  return notHello(currentMonth);
};
update1();
```